# Why are C++ header functions put in a seperate file?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm working my way through a C++ tutorial, and in one of the articles on the preprocessor/header files the author creates 2 'header files' (not the technical term, of course), example.h and example.cpp.  In example.h he puts the forward declarations for the functions and the header guard, and in example.cpp the actual body of the functions.  Why is this?  I tried putting the body of the function in the example.h file and it worked just fine, so why does he put it separately?  Is it customary, or does it pose problems in bigger problems?  Or what?

Can someone please enlighten me on this...

Comment: `#include` is the equivalent of copying and pasting the contents of a file into your code

Comment: So...it's okay to have multiple declarations, but not definitions?

Comment: Well yeah: http://ideone.com/iWsAZN

Comment: Okay, makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has a rule called the *one-definition rule* that says that every function needs to be defined once and only once (there are a few exceptions to this rule, but we'll ignore them for now.) The function prototype typically included in a header file is a *declaration* saying that the function exists, and the implementation in the .cpp file is the *definition* giving the code for the function.

If you put the definition of the function in a header file and then include the header file in multiple places, you'll get linker errors because you're breaking the one definition rule - each .cpp file that's compiled will have its own copy of the definition of the function. On the other hand, if you just put the *declaration* in the header and then put the *definition* in a single source file, then there's only one definition and nothing will break.

There are a few exceptions for the one definition rule. First, all inline functions are exempt from ODR, so you could potentially put function definitions in a header file if you mark all the functions `inline`, though this is generally not considered a good idea for all but the smallest functions. Second, template functions are exempt from the ODR, which (among other things) is one of the reasons you see template functions defined in headers.

Comment: What are inline and template functions?

Comment: @wolf_adventures1909 I don't think I can explain them in the space in this comment. Look up the `inline` keyword for an explanation of inline functions. For template functions, you'll probably want to look for something like "C++ templates" on Google. Happy hunting!

Comment: Thanks for you help, been very useful and I will of course look that up ;)

Answer (score 1):

Put the function body in example.h.  Then, when you write a second .cpp file that also includes example.h, and link it with example.cpp, then you'll get a linker error.  The linker will see 2 definitions of the function in example.h.

Comment: Not sure if I understand...  But, the structure would be like this: main.cpp includes example.h and example.cpp which also includes example.h resulting in two instances of exampleFunc() in main.cpp?  Or is it that when compiling they are automatically linked (no includes)?

Comment: Right, resulting in two instances of exampleFunc() in a.out (or whatever the name of your output binary is.)

Answer (score 0):

Becouse in the header file you only declare functions that is really important when you want to use a custom linking configuration.  For example if a function is defined in a file object and is used  in an another object the linker must have the same reference for this function to link the two different files.